# PHP - Strtotime - Add hours

Tags: php, strtotime

I have this variable:

```
$timestamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %h:%M:%S %a", time ());
```

I simply want to add three hours and echo it out.

I have seen the way where you can do the 60 * 60 * 3 method or the hard code "+ 3 hours" where it understands the words.

What is the best way of getting this result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$timestamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %h:%M:%S %a", time() + 3*60*60)
```

`3*60*60` is the best way

Answer (score 20):

The best way is what you think is more readable. The following expressions are identical:

```
time() + 3 * 60 * 60

strtotime('+3 hours')
```

Answer (score 12):

i always do like this

```
$current_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$new_time = strtotime($current_time . "+3hours");
echo $new_time;
```

or

```
$new_time = mktime(date('H')+3, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
$new_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $new_time);
echo $new_time;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just add seconds to add hours:**

```
strtotime($your_date)+2*60*60
```

This will add two hours in your date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DateTime::modify`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) to add time, but I would just do `time()+10800`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = new DateTime("+ 3 hour");
$timestamp = $time->format('Y-M-d h:i:s a');
```

Clear and concise :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go 'modern':

```
$d = new DateTime();
$d->add(new DateInterVal('P3H'));
$timestamp = $d->format('Y-M-d h:i:s a');
```

refs: [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) object

Comment: That would be DateInterval('PT3H'), IMHO,

Answer (score 0):

$currentTime = time(); // Get the current timestamp

$newTime = $currentTime + 3 * 60; // Add 3 minutes (3 * 60 seconds) to the current timestamp

$formattedTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newTime);
echo $formattedTime;

Comment: Hi, and welcome, normally it is a good practices to share a bit of text / explanation additional to your code.