# printing the next hour with .date("h:i:sa"); php function

Tags: php, date

This php function .date("h:i:sa"); prints the time now what I should do if I want to prints the time now  plus one hour?

I have tried this but with same result.

```
echo "" . date("h:i:sa"+3600) ;
```

Comment: the first part of `date` is a format string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding 1 hour to time variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552106/adding-1-hour-to-time-variable) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076334/php-strtotime-add-hours

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple ways to do this in PHP. The easiest is to combine `date()` and `strtotime()`:

```
echo date('h:i:sa', strtotime('+1 hour'));
```

You can also use [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) which is daylight savings time aware:

```
echo (new DateTime('+1 hour'))->format('h:i:sa');
```

Both of these use the [relative date format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) "+1 hour" to add one hour to the current date and time.

Output:- https://eval.in/812700

Comment: this one is best suitable answer

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `next hour`. I love PHP due to simple datetime methods :)

```
echo date('h:i:sa', strtotime('next hour'));
```